# All requests 404 with Phonegap 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have loaded everything required from the documentation to enable internet connectivity but all and any internet requests are received with a `404` return code.

I know that the file I am trying to reach is assessable across domain. Seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/hutber/VN864/

[image]

I am running this same code inside my app and on click `404` is returned in the alert.

To test my connection I am running:

```
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    if(typeof Connection!=="undefined"){
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
```

This returns the connection as expected. Currently `WiFi connection`

**config.xml**

```
<access origin="*" />
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

**AndriodManiest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**JS used to call said http request**

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://stage.sexdiaries.co.uk/app/users/login',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'uname': values.uname,
                    'pword': values.pword
                },
                crossDomain: true,
                error: function(data){
                    c(data.status);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    c('success: '+data);
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if(data.privateKey){
                        $.jStorage.set('uid',data.ud.uid); //store user ID in the localStorage to persist
                        sessionStorage.setItem('privateKey',data.privateKey); //store privateKey in session so it disapears when the user closers the tab
                        Backbone.history.loadUrl('');
                    }
                }
            });
```

So I know that the connection is active. Do I really have a connection? Am I crazy? How can I reach this http request?

**Added Info with iFrame**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://stage.sexdiaries.co.uk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This gives the following error:

[image]
So to 100% make sure I have access to the internet I've added an iframe that should 100% work.

Comment: Th network error may be something different than a 404. Can you add the adb-log? You may also use http://debug.phonegap.com/ and take a look for network and console.

Comment: sadly, for whatever reason compiling with debug.phonegap.com just breaks my app. Still trying to work this part out. But, i'll have a close look at the adb-log.. If i can find them ;)

Comment: This is what I could find on the subject: `10-12 00:38:08.865    2129-2129/? E/WifiP2pStateTracker﹕ getNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: WIFI_P2P[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true`

Comment: Must say, I am confused now. Which config.xml do I use when complinging on my local machine, config.xml in the root or `/res/xml/config.xml` Its all a little unclear I do believe.

Comment: hey @Jamie. did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I believe it was as simple as I was editing the wrong config.xml. You want the config that is located in the Root of the phonegap folder. For example `phonegap/www/config.xml` Let me know if this is correct?

Comment: Yes, This was i did. i wrote there. `<access origin="http://myhosy.com" subdomains="true" />` that didnt workd then i tired `<access origin="http://myhost.com*" subdomains="true" />` and that didnt work either.

Comment: It seems to work good when i mark <access origin="*" />

Comment: awesome :D Glad the question helped.

Comment: It seems to work good on Android/IOS when i mark <access origin="*" />. But i dont think its the best way to get it work.

Comment: I would love to know if someone figured this one out. I've reproduced this problem as well on my device. access origin etc are all setup correctly. I've tested with different urls etc, everything remote is basically denied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've ran into this problem as well this evening (see my comment on the original question), but I'm happy to report that I figured this out.

It turns out that it has everything to do with an update in Cordova for Android 4.0.0. From the Changlelog:

> - Whitelist functionality is now provided via plugin (CB-7747) The
>     whitelist has been enhanced to be more secure and configurable
>     Setting of Content-Security-Policy is now supported by the framework
>     (see details in plugin readme) You will need to add the new
>     cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin Legacy whitelist behaviour is still
>     available via plugin (although not recommended).

So the way to solve this is to install the plugin:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

After which you can configure which host can be navigated to, for test purposes you could set it to:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

This also explains the failing of the iframe test. I verified this fix in my project and it all just works now.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you may forgot to allow access to your server, you may use  to your config.xml file to allow access to all urls just for testing.